# Can a Meta Tag be Spoofed? (Is a Metatag Sufficient to Declare a Page is Protected?)

Tags: authentication

### Background

I am working as a front-end developer, and I have very little security experience. We are working with a very obscure backend setup, using a [4D database](http://www.4d.com/) and [WebClerk](http://www.jpods.com/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=WebClerk.HTMLCommands) on top of it.

WebClerk allows for logged in users. All pages are actual `.html` pages, with specific WebClerk code which is processed on pageload (similar to PHP). To tell if a page is protected, it uses a custom `meta` tag in the `head`. When the page is being read in by the server, it checks to see if the security `meta` tag exists, and if so, does a logged in check, and then pushes over to an error page if not.

### Question

Is a `meta` tag secure? Can it be spoofed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything provided by the client to the server can be altered by the client, including any HTML content/tags.

Look at products like Burp Proxy to give you an idea about the power available to the client. It allows you to manually intercept responses then inspect and edit them before sending. It's a very common tool for hackers (and security pros) to use.

Answer (score 1):

The real question you need to ask yourself is, can your user edit the html files? If your users can edit or upload html files, you'll need to make sure that your server are setup such that it doesn't process them code (i.e. they're served as simple static file) or that only privileged, trusted users can upload to areas that allows the pages to be processed as server side code.

Another consideration is that you may want to check that the meta tag aren't present in the final output of the page. This may leak authorization information, and depending on your security model, this may be an issue.

Whether you use meta tag or database or something else to implement authorization is irrelevant. What matters is that the component that enforces authorization must be the server (and not the client). Your client runs on the user's machine, you must assume that the user can do anything on their machine, like not honoring any code you asked the client to execute or disclosing to the user the content of anything traveling between the server and the client.